# Zend : Displaying content generated from menu controller in admin module in layout

Tags: php, zend-framework, model-view-controller

This is a custom CMS where menu list can be edited in backend and then need to be displayed in front end layout.

Menu controller is in -**/application/modules/admin/controllers**

and the code for render action is :

```
<?php

class Admin_MenuController extends CMS_Controller_AdminbaseController
{
public function renderAction()
    {
        $menu = $this->_request->getParam('menu');
        $mdlMenuItems = new Model_MenuItems();
        $menuItems = $mdlMenuItems->getItemsByMenu($menu);

        if(count($menuItems)>0){
            foreach($menuItems as $item){
                $label = $item->label;
                if(!empty($item->link)){
                    $uri = $item->link;
                }else{
                    $uri = '/page/open/id/' . $item->pageId;
                }
                $itemArray[] = array(
                    'label' => $label,
                    'uri'   => $uri
                );
            } 

            $container = new Zend_Navigation($itemArray);
            $this->view->navigation()->setContainer($container);

        } 
    }
}
```

When rendered in - **/application/modules/admin/views/scripts/menu/render.phtml** using

```
<? echo $this->navigation()->menu(); ?>
```

it renders fine, but instead I want to render it in **/application/layouts/scripts**. 
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I know what you need to do I just don't have the code handy to demonstrate. You need to develop a front controller plugin that hooks into `preDispatch()` to set the menu and assign the data to the `navigation()->menu()` placeholder

Answer (score 0):

go to Zend_View_Helper create exapmle.php as an example;

on it insert function

```
 public function abc()
{
//insert your code here
}
```

then go to layout.phtml and call it

```
echo $this->abc();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can render it in layout this way `<?= $this->action('render', 'menu', 'admin');?>` 
Additionally you can pass some parametrs in array.
Hope this helps you.